# Append code to toggle image when song is playing

Tags: jquery, css, audio, toggle, background-image

I use this code to play and pause song samples, and there are multiple instances on the page. I would like to append some code after song.play() that changes the background-image of this instance only of the .playback class to pausebutton.gif and then back again to playbutton.gif when the button is pressed again. Is this possible with a class because of the multiple instances on the page? Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".playback").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var song = $(this).next('audio').get(0);
   if (song.paused)
     song.play()
   else
     song.pause()
   });
   });
```

```
<style>
.playback:link   
{background:url('images/playbutton.gif');display:block;width:18px;height:18px;}
</style>

<a class="playback" href="#"></a><audio id="wonderful"><source src="audio/wonderful.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"  /></audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add to your CSS:

```
.playback.playing {
    background: url('images/pausebutton.gif');
 }
```

This style will now refer to elements with the classes `playback` and `playing`.

Then in your JavaScript:

```
$(".playback").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var song = $(this).next('audio').get(0);
    if (song.paused) {
        song.play();
        $(this).addClass("playing");
    } else {
        song.pause();
        $(this).removeClass("playing");
    }
});
```

Within the function set to occur on click, `$(this)` will refer specifically to the element (with class `playback`) that was clicked.  So the `addClass` method would apply the `playing` class only to the link for the song that was played.  (In this example I also used `removeClass` to remove the `playing` class when the song is paused.)

An even better idea, if possible, would be to combine playbutton.gif and pausebutton.gif into one 36x18 image called, say, playbackbuttons.gif, and change your CSS to:

```
.playback:link {
    background: url('images/playbackbuttons.gif');
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}

.playback.playing {
    background-position: right top;
}
```

(The JavaScript would still be the same as what I wrote above.)

This way, the pause button image will be loaded when the page first loads, and not the first time a song a played.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question about multiple instances and for suggesting the single image CSS. I have done this and combined with the $(this) suggestion below, it's a beautiful thing. I guess I was stuck thinking I had to actually change the image in the code - never thought about changing the class. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`e` will refer to jQuery.Event object, so you need to use $(this):

```
$(".playback").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var song = $(this).next('audio').get(0);
    if (song.paused) {
        song.play();
        $(this).addClass("playing");
    } else {
        song.pause();
        $(this).removeClass("playing");
    }
});
```

I used `color` in [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/9fm22/) but you have to change `background-image`

Comment: Yes, $(this) was necessary. Thank you for that demo - looking at your example with html instead of an image gave me an idea for another page I have to do! So thank you! It was really difficult to choose a correct answer here.

Comment: Not sure why I went with e...$(this) is absolutely correct. I'm updating my answer, no reason not to.

Comment: the only thing I cannot understand is: why do I provide new ideas for questioner and help someone to change his incorrect answer, but still his answer is accepted, not mine